# Array Syntax Confusion

Tags: c, arrays, string

It is a known thing that array names decay into pointer such as `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`. I stumbled upon a question asking me predict the output of:

```
int main(void)
{
   printf("%c", "abcdefgh"[4]);
   return 0;
}
```

The answer they say is `e` and the reason given by them is as `a[4]` gets converted into `*(a+4)` where `a` is base address of array `a` on similar lines we can find the output of above question.

But how I don't understand as with `a[i]` decaying into `*(a+i)` because compiler treats it that way but in the code snippet above how and why we will treat `"abcdef"[4]` this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will wonder even more if I say that you can write even the following way :)

```
printf( "%c\n", 4["abcdefgh"] );
```

String literals in C have types of character arrays. Thus string literal "abcdefgh" has type `char[9]`. It includes also the terminating zero.

In expressions arrays as you correctly mentioned decay to pointers to their first elements. So the string literal decays to a pointer of type `char *`that points to the first character of the literal that is to `'a'`

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]`
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to
>   `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer,
>   `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

Thus this expression `(*((E1)+(E2)))` does not depend on whether the initial record was `E1[E2]` or `E2[E1]`

Returning to your code shippet you have that in this expression

```
4["abcdefgh"]
```

the string literal is converted to the pointer to its first character. You can imagine this like

```
char *p = "abcdefgh";
```

and you will get

`4[p]` is equivalent to `*( 4 + p )` and results in lvalue of character `'e'`

Answer (score 3):

`"abcdefgh"[4]` is equivalent to `*("abcdefgh" + 4)`. When used in an expression (except when it is an operand of unary `&` and `sizeof` operator) `"abcdefgh"` represents the base address of string.

In general, remember that one can use a string literal wherever `char *` pointer is allowed. In the snippet

```
char *ptr;
p = "abcdefgh";
```

the assignment doesn't copy the characters to `p` instead it makes `p` points the **first character of the string**. C allows pointers to be subscripted, so we can subscript string literals:

```
char ch;  
ch = "abcdefgh"[4];
```

Comment: "When used in an expression" – no, not in any expression, only when it's not operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operators.

Answer (score 0):

`"abcdefgh"` is an array. It is an array of characters, similar (but not identical) to as if you had declared a variable of type `char[9]` and `static` storage duration:

```
static char str[9] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 0 };
```

Hence, you can index it just like any other array, using the `[]` subscript operator.